# What is causing a 'TypeError: 'int' object is not callable' error in my Tic Tac Toe game with AI?

Tags: python

hey guys im buildind TICK TACK TOE game with AI and when i run the code i get this error (

```
File "C:\Users\dejan\Desktop\pyth programs\TicTackToewAI\main.py", line 102, in miniMax
    temp_board.marked_square(row,col,self.player)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

and i dont know why and that why im asking you if anyone wants to help me find a error in this code
main .py

```
import copy

import pygame
import numpy as np
import sys
from constance import *
import random
pygame.init()
win=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("TICK TACK TOE AI")
win.fill(BG_COLOR)
run=True

class Board():
    def__init__(self):
        self.squares=np.zeros((ROWS,COLS))
        self.empty_squares=self.squares
        self.marked_square=0

    def markSquare(self,row,col,player):
        self.squares[row][col]=player
        self.marked_square+=1

    def isFull(self):
        return self.marked_square==9

    def isempty(self):
        return self.marked_square==0


    def emptySquare(self,row,col):
        return self.squares[row][col]==0

    def getEmptySquares(self):
        empty_sqrs=[]
        for row in range(ROWS):
            for col in range(COLS):
                if self.emptySquare(row,col):
                    empty_sqrs.append((row,col))
        return empty_sqrs

    def final_State(self):
        for col in range(COLS):
            if self.squares[0][col]==self.squares[1][col]==self.squares[2][col]!=0:
                return self.squares[0][col]

        for row in range(ROWS):
            if self.squares[row][0] == self.squares[row][1] == self.squares[row][2] != 0:
                return self.squares[row][0]

        if self.squares[0][0]==self.squares[1][1]==self.squares[2][2]:
            return self.squares[1][1]

        if self.squares[2][0] == self.squares[1][1] == self.squares[0][2]:
            return self.squares[1][1]

        return 0


class AI():
    def__init__(self,level=1,player=2):
        self.level=level
        self.player=player

    def rnd_choice(self,board):
        empty_sqrs=board.getEmptySquares()
        idx=random.randrange(0,len(empty_sqrs))
        return empty_sqrs[idx]

    def miniMax(self,board,maximizing):
        case=board.final_State()
        if case==1:
            return 1,None
        if case==2:
            return -1,None
        elif board.isFull():
            return 0,None

        if maximizing:
            max_eval = -100
            best_move = None
            empty_sqrs = board.getEmptySquares()

            for (row, col) in empty_sqrs:
                temp_board = copy.deepcopy(board)
                temp_board.marked_square(row, col,1)
                eval = self.miniMax(temp_board, False)[0]

                if eval > max_eval:
                    max_eval = eval
                    best_move = (row, col)

            return max_eval, best_move

        elif not maximizing:
            min_eval=100
            best_move=None
            empty_sqrs=board.getEmptySquares()

            for (row,col)in empty_sqrs:
                temp_board=copy.deepcopy(board)
                temp_board.marked_square(row,col,self.player)
                eval=self.miniMax(temp_board,True)[0]

                if eval<min_eval:
                    min_eval=eval
                    best_move=(row,col)

            return min_eval,best_move





    def eval(self,main_board):
        if self.level==0:
            eval='random'
            move=self.rnd_choice(main_board)
        else:
           eval,move= self.miniMax(main_board,False)
        print(f'AI has chosen to mark the square in pos{move}witha an eval of{eval}')

        return move

class Game():
    def__init__(self):
        self.board=Board()
        self.ai=AI()
        self.player = 1
        self.gameMode='ai'
        self.running=True
        self.showLines()

    def showLines(self):
        pygame.draw.line(win,LINE_COLOR,(sQSIZE,0),(sQSIZE,HEIGHT),LINE_WIDTH)
        pygame.draw.line(win, LINE_COLOR, (WIDTH-sQSIZE, 0), (WIDTH-sQSIZE, HEIGHT), LINE_WIDTH)
        pygame.draw.line(win, LINE_COLOR, (0, sQSIZE), (WIDTH, sQSIZE), LINE_WIDTH)
        pygame.draw.line(win, LINE_COLOR, (0, HEIGHT-sQSIZE), (WIDTH, HEIGHT-sQSIZE), LINE_WIDTH)

    def drawFig(self,row,col):
        if self.player==1:
            start_desc=(col*sQSIZE+OFFSET,row*sQSIZE+OFFSET)
            end_desc=(col*sQSIZE+sQSIZE-OFFSET,row*sQSIZE+sQSIZE-OFFSET)
            pygame.draw.line(win,CROSS_COLOR,start_desc,end_desc,CROSS_WIDTH)

            start_asc = (col * sQSIZE + OFFSET, row * sQSIZE+sQSIZE -OFFSET)
            end_asc = (col * sQSIZE + sQSIZE - OFFSET, row * sQSIZE + OFFSET)
            pygame.draw.line(win, CROSS_COLOR, start_asc, end_asc, CROSS_WIDTH)

        elif self.player==2:
            center=(col*sQSIZE+sQSIZE//2,row*sQSIZE+sQSIZE//2)
            pygame.draw.circle(win,CIRCLE_COLOR,center,CIRCLE_RADIOUS,CIRCLE_WIDTH)

    def nextTurn(self):
        self.player=self.player%2+1


def main():
    game=Game()
    board=game.board
    ai=game.ai
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos=event.pos
                row=pos[1]//sQSIZE
                cols=pos[0]//sQSIZE
                if board.emptySquare(row,cols):
                    board.markSquare(row,cols,game.player)
                    game.drawFig(row,cols)
                    game.nextTurn()

        if game.gameMode=='ai' and game.player==ai.player:
            pygame.display.update()
            row,cols=ai.eval(board)
            board.markSquare(row, cols, ai.player)
            game.drawFig(row, cols)
            game.nextTurn()


        pygame.display.update()




main()
```

constance.py

```
WIDTH,HEIGHT=600,600

BG_COLOR=(20,170,156)
ROWS=3
COLS=3
sQSIZE=WIDTH//COLS
LINE_COLOR=(23,145,135)
LINE_WIDTH=15

CROSS_COLOR=(66,66,66)
CROSS_WIDTH=20
CIRCLE_COLOR=(239,231,200)

CIRCLE_WIDTH=15
CIRCLE_RADIOUS=sQSIZE//4

OFFSET=50
```

Comment: I guess you mean to do `temp_board.markSquare` instead of `temp_board.marked_square`. `Board.markSquare()` is a method, `Board.marked_square` is an int attribute.

Answer (score 0):

On some places you're using this class member as a variable:

```
return self.marked_square==9
```

and on other places as a function:

```
temp_board.marked_square(row, col,1)
```

Comment: TNX guys that was very very helpfull i dont know how i missed it...I just have one question now i get a diffend fail in this is that(File "C:\Users\dejan\Desktop\pyth programs\TicTackToewAI\main.py", line 179, in main
    row,cols=ai.eval(board)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object) Does anyone know why??

Comment: @kretze, your `AI.miniMax()`  method can return `None` as a move result. The `eval()` method propagates this `None` move, which cannot be broken into `rows, cols`. You need to add a check for this situation.